# Arrange FlowLayoutPanel controls to take the least amount of space

Tags: c#, .net, flowlayoutpanel

I use FlowLayoutPanel control and i wonder if there is anyway to perform auto layout of controls so that they will take as low space as possible?
For example, add 1 control with 100px width, three controls with 500px width and again 1 control with 100px.

It should look like this:

```
##Control1##
##############Control2##########################
##############Control3##########################
##############Control4##########################
##Control5##
```

As you see, some space is being wasted, is there anyway to optimize it's location to achive something like this without manualy reposition?

```
##Control1## ##Control5##
##############Control2##########################
##############Control3##########################
##############Control4##########################
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.flowdirection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: sadly, but this doesn't resolve my problem

Comment: Are the `FlowBreak` properties of items inside the Panel set to False ?

Comment: Yes, all control have flow break propery on false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to arrange controls to take the least amount of space:

(top : initial layout, bottom : resulting layout)

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var flowLayoutPanel = flowLayoutPanel1;
        ReorganizeFlowLayoutPanel(flowLayoutPanel);
    }

    private static void ReorganizeFlowLayoutPanel(FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel) {
        var width = flowLayoutPanel.Width;
        var controls = flowLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType<Control>().ToList();
        var ascending = new List<Control>(controls.OrderBy(s => s.Width));
        var descending = new List<Control>(controls.OrderByDescending(s => s.Width));

        var list = new List<Control>();
        while (ascending.Count > 0) {
            Control smallest = ascending[0];
            ascending.RemoveAt(0);
            if (ascending.Count == 0) {
                list.Add(smallest);
                break;
            }
            foreach (var largest in descending) {
                if (smallest.Width + largest.Width < width) {
                    list.Add(smallest);
                    list.Add(largest);
                    ascending.Remove(largest);
                    descending.Remove(largest);
                    descending.Remove(smallest);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var control in list) {
            flowLayoutPanel.Controls.SetChildIndex(control, i++);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you might face an *'user experience'* issue while using it, like you expect some of them being in a particular order. What you can do to address such issue is to set the [Control.Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) property to some string such as `"Priority=1"`, `"Priority=2"`, etc ...

Then replace the definition of `ascending` by:

`var ascending = new List<Control>(controls.OrderBy(s => s.Width).ThenBy(s=>(string)s.Tag) );`

**Arrange without priority tags:**

[image]

**Arrange with priority tags:**

[image]

Example I've shown is really simple, you might want to roll your own logic to differentiate your controls better.

**Note:** it is a really naive approach, if you are looking for a more sophisticated algorithm then you should take some inspiration from a sprite sheet texture maker such as http://spritesheetpacker.codeplex.com/.

---

### The other way around: (original answer)

You can somehow *re-organize* the controls using this method:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            var flowLayoutPanel = flowLayoutPanel1;
            ReorganizeFlowLayoutPanel(flowLayoutPanel);
        }

        private static void ReorganizeFlowLayoutPanel(FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel) {
            var controls = flowLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType<Control>().OrderBy(s => s.Width);
            var index = 0;
            foreach (var tuple in controls) {
                flowLayoutPanel.Controls.SetChildIndex(tuple, index++);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Initial layout:**

[image]

**New layout:**

[image]

Note: they are ordered in the order they are discovered, i.e. if you'd like no. 3 after no. 4 you will have to manually place it after no. 4 before reorganizing the panel.

Comment: hmm i need something opposite from what you showed, i need to go from your "new layout" to "initial layout", to have as low wasted space as possible

Comment: Sorry ! :D Check my edit for the other way around, should be easy to understand how I did. I've also tested to add to a few controls (and an odd count of them), it hasn't exploded so I guess it's okay ;)

Comment: Nice, it seems that this is exactly what I need :) I will study your code to implement this into my project. Thanks